Issue with recording a flow in jmeter using chrome browser
i am using apache jmeter on windows 11 in my office laptop , i have installed jdk 18 for that , and installed a jmeter root certificate  too. i have added transaction controller under a thread group and a view tree results under HTTP script recorder,, i have set the port to 8080 and gave a demo website link,qhen i switch on the proxy and try recording the flow ,i am getting your connection is not private issue in the chrome brower..i have tried in few other ways to resolve this,,that is by clearing cache and cookies in chrome browser etc,but i am unable to record the flow amd get requests inder the transaction controller in jmeter ,please find me a way to solve this issue.
I tried removing proxyserver.jks file and ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt file from the bin folder and remove any existing jmeter root certificate in the trusted root certificates in chrome settings, again started a sample recording in http test script recorder by setting port to 8080,inorder to regenerate the proxyserver.jks and ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt files in bin folder newly..
As I wish,those 2 files got created .using that ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt file I installed the jmeter root certificate and it have a validity of 1 week that is till 02.10.2024, now after setting the proxy on .if I try recording..I am unable to access the website in chrome .I am getting "your connection is not private" issue...I have removed the certificate many times and installed it.but still I am not able to access the website when the proxy is on and record

You will get the your connection is not private "issue" because JMeter's certificate is self-signed and is not known to any certification authority.
So you can simply ignore the warning, click "Advanced" button and there will be the link called "Proceed to whatever-site-you-are-recording (unsafe)"

Also be aware of an alternative way for recording a JMeter test: JMeter Chrome Extension, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates and will be able to record a JMeter test using just Chrome browser
